# Stuck on how to factor $2x^3+3x^2-8x+3$ without trial/error

Tags: algebra-precalculus, cubics

I know this is pretty basic, but I am unable to factor $2x^3+3x^2-8x+3$ without the use of trial/error. Even the rational roots theorem requires trial/error, as you need to implement the rational roots theorem to find at least one of the roots. The only other way (besides the rational root theorem) I found to factor this was to add two terms and subtract two terms. However, this is also pretty useless as it too requires number sense and trial/check. I know a solution to my problem would be graphing, but that would take too much time (even by finding the derivative and critical values) and I have no graphing calculator.

**My question is, what method would I implement to factor without trial/error**? Additionally, if this expression would be set equal to zero and by chance this expression has all complex/irrational roots ($x^3-2=0$), would this method work?

Comment: $1$ is a root. Your polynomial divided by $(x-1)$ is a quadratic.

Comment: How did you discover 1 as a root? Did you do it with a method without trial/error?

Comment: @YashJain If you mean "*without trial/error*" in the strictest of senses (e.g. not even allowing to "see" that $1$ is a root because $2+3-8+3=0$), then pretty much the only eligible answer is the [cubic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_solution_to_the_cubic_equation_with_real_coefficients).

Comment: I realized it is 1, but what would happen if the solutions composed only of irrational/complex roots?

Comment: *Without trial/error* means with an algorithm, i.e. cubic formula

Comment: Would this be the only possible way?

Comment: Y: I think I may have it. Are you talking about factoring quickly because you are involved in some sort of contests? If so, checking for $\pm 1$ as roots, for a polynomial with integer coefficients, is the fastest technique available, and should always be done first; this is in a contest situation.

Comment: Meanwhile, i do not know a meaning for ryme, but rime is an old word for ice, http://www.dictionary.com/browse/rime

Comment: Read it all : D

Answer (score 2):

$$  2+3+3 = 8  $$
.........................

Comment: What do I do with those numbers?

Comment: I realized it is 1, but what would happen if the solutions composed only of irrational/complex roots?

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align*}2x^3+\color{red}{3x^2}-8x+3 & =2x^3\color{red}{-2x^2+5x^2}-8x+3\\ & =2x^2(x-1)+(5x-3)(x-1)\\ & =(x-1)(2x^2+5x-3)\\ & =(x-1)(2x-1)(x+3)\end{align*}$$

Comment: "The only other way (besides the rational root theorem) I found to factor this was to add two terms and subtract two terms. However, this is also pretty useless as it too requires number sense and trial/check."

Comment: I guess this is adding/subtracting one term, but it still requires trial/check.

Comment: @YashJain Not much guess and check actually... It didn't take me very long as long as you look at the constant term and the linear term, and try to make the quadratic factorable.

Comment: @YashJain Alike, if you consider rational root theorem guess and check, then your only bet is the cubic formula. Which is like killing a fly with a sledgehammer: **overkill**

Answer (score 1):

Your rejection of the
rational roots theorem
seems irrational to me
since the number of
possibilities is quite small.

Here's how I did it
without any trial or error:

I gave it to Wolfy
and was told that
the roots are
-3, 1/2, and 1.

The alternative is to
use the explicit formula
(after eliminating
the quadratic term).